Python Add-in Shows up as Missing then Works after Logging in Again Through Citrix
I have created a Python Add-in that works well when installing it through the add-in installer or when adding the add-in directory folder to the registry string (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ESRI\Desktop10.8\Settings\AddInFolders) in the Citrix GOLDEN Image Server.
I can open the MXD the editor calls and see the Add-in and extension is currently working as designed.  Save the MXD with the new tool placements and then have the start-up script call the new MXD.  I run the start-up script to call the MXD and it starts as designed with the Add-in tool working as designed.
ArcMap 10.8.1
OS Windows 19
I then have the Citrix team push out the newly implemented setup to child servers.  Once this is implemented, I fire off the Citrix application and the Add-in shows up as missing.
I close the ArcMap Editor and then open the application again and the add-in works as designed.
Why does the add-in not show the first time a user logs in?
For each child server this process has to happen (user logs in and back out and back in) for the add-in to function properly.
I have also installed the Sample Add-in from Creating a Python add-in button  and it acts the same way.
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
class ZoomToSelectedFeatures(object):
"""Implementation for zoom_addin_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        # Get the current map document and the first data frame.
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        # Call the zoomToSelectedFeatures() method of the data frame class
        df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()


Are you able to see this with a simple test Python addin that you can present the code for?

I have installed the ESRI Sample Python (Zoom To Selected) Add-in from their website.  Same functionality as mentioned in the description.  Works on second time opening the Citrix application.
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-button.htm
